# Wait for MySQL query in async function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I'm querying my database in an async function (via the `mysql` library), but I can't seem to get my function to properly wait for the query to finish before continuing.

Code:

```
async (eventName, eventArgs, app) => {

  ...

  prefix = "!";

  if(msg.channel.type !== "dm")
    database.query(`SELECT prefix FROM guilds WHERE \`id\`=${msg.guild.id}`, (err, res) => {
      if(err)
        return console.error("db", `${err.message}`);

      if(res.length > 0)
        if(res[0].prefix)
          prefix = res[0].prefix;

      console.log(`from within callback ${prefix}`);
      console.log(`returned from query ${res[0].prefix}`);
    });

  console.log(`prefix in standard flow ${prefix}`);

  ...

}
```

The console outputs the following:

```
prefix in standard flow !
from within callback -
returned from query -
```

All 3 should output `-`, but outside the query callback it is `!`. It appears to be that my async function isn't waiting for the query callback function to finish before continuing, not a scope issue.

I've also tried `await`ing the database.query function, but to no avail.

Comment: You need to `await` a promise.

Comment: @SLaks I'm aware of that, however not sure how to go about it — I'm completely clueless when it comes to creating promises. When you say that, do you mean that I need to create it surrounding the `database.query` function, then resolve the promise once the value of `prefix` has been set?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You should wrap your async functions to return promises.

Comment: Consider using `mysql2`, which has built-in [promise support](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-promise-wrapper).

Comment: @SLaks [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45512829/3993995) showed me how — thank you for letting me know that's the correct way to do it, I'll definitely be doing a lot of that in the future.

Comment: @robertklep Since I'm relatively early into my database integration that's still viable regardless of other compatibility possibilities. Thanks for letting me know about that, I'll check into it!

Comment: @ffxhand it aims to match the `mysql` API, but it's more performant and has more features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `async`/`await`:

```js
async (eventName, eventArgs, app) => {
  let prefix = '!';
  const query = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    database.query(`SELECT prefix FROM guilds WHERE \`id\`=${msg.guild.id}`, (err, res) => {
      if(err)
        return reject("db", `${err.message}`);

      if(res.length > 0 && res[0].prefix)
          prefix = res[0].prefix;

      console.log(`from within promise ${prefix}`);
      console.log(`returned from query ${res[0].prefix}`);
      resolve();
    });
  });

  await query;
  console.log(`prefix in standard flow ${prefix}`);
}
```

Comment: I've slightly modified your answer to fit my needs, but that exact same concept works perfectly for my needs. Thank you, @PeterMader!